# Echo the email captured from Facebook permissions

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, csv

I am using the Facebook API with PHP and have used scope to retrieve the 'email' permissions.

I can access these permissions fine but how can I now use PHP code to now extract the user directly on to a page using echo or into a text file (csv)?

Comment: what have you tried? Does looking at the example code [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) help? i.e. something like `print_r($facebook->api('/me','GET'));`?

Answer (score 0):

Do an HTTP GET to `/me?fields=email` will return the current user object with the email property included.